# LogicException after upgrading to magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, vagrant

After upgrading to Magento 2.2, this error happened to me

> Exception #0 (LogicException): View file '/var/www/tuptip/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print_renderers.xml'
>   is indistinguishable from the file
>   '/var/www/tuptip/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_print_renderers.xml'.

And can't access my development site, it says is from a magento module, but I wouldn't like to touch a magento core file.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that not only Magento, all my others php apps are having trouble after I upgraded to Mac Os High Sierra. I am using a Vagrant box and syncing folders with NFS. I guess it's because APFS. So... I switched by the default sync and everything is working.

We can see more here: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/8788

Comment: yes, I have the same issue with upgrading Mac to Os High Sierra. I will try your solution.

Comment: it's not ideal and much slower, tough. This solution worked for me better http://www.qed42.com/blog/macos-sierra-issues-vagrant , but also not ideal.